# find function in Beautifulsoup return None

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to fetch and track price for a product from Amazon but I get None as find function result!.

Here is my code. What's my mistake and what am I missing?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.amazon.ca/Sony-WH1000XM3-Canceling-Headphones-WH-1000XM3/dp/B07G4MNFS1/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=sony+wh-1000xm3&qid=1574044279&sr=8-3'    
headers = {"User-Agent" : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')    
title = soup.find(id="productTitle")
#price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice")    
print(title)
```

Appreciate your help everyone.

Comment: It is not finding what you are looking for. What value are you expecting title to be in your example above?

Comment: Agree! I am looking for the name of product in page span as identified by id. The question is why it can't find it? I am sure that soup contains the part I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved! Here is the solution:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(soup.encode("utf-16"),"html.parser")

title = soup1.find(id="productTitle").get_text()
price = soup1.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()

print(title.strip(), price)
```